# Removing role when reaction is removed

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to remove a role when a reaction is removed. I already have the 'add reaction' roles that work perfectly. However, whenever I try to run this, it ends up printing "removed None" (none as the role) which means it doesn't remove the role. I think it has something to do with getting the roles. Here is the code:

```py
 @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        
        messageID=962844879044628510

        if messageID== payload.message_id:
            guild= self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            member = guild.get_member (payload.user_id)
        
        if str(payload.emoji) == "<a:black_drip:961304023401652274>":
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='evnt')


        elif str(payload.emoji) == "<a:Uzi_spin:962831415114879056>":
            role = get(guild.roles, name='chat revive')


        elif str(payload.emoji) == "<a:BlackFire:934621316298964992>":
            role = get(guild.roles, name='gw')

        elif str(payload.emoji) == "<a:Black_LV:961428631803027466>":
            role = get(guild.roles, name='vc')

        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
            
        if role is not None:
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
        print(f"Removed {role} from {member}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw reaction events return `PartialEmoji`. Never rely on the rendering behavior. You can compare them by using their IDs, such as `my_part_emoji.id == 123456`.

Also, using raw events may not be a good idea - you need access to the messages. It would be better to use the normal reaction event instead.